# SQL server unlimited join/union?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table like this

```
Activity | ActivityId
Skiing   |     1
Swimming |     2  
climbing |     3
```

And one like this (Activity replaced by activity)

```
ActivityId | ShouldBeReplacedWithActivityId
   1       |          2
   2       |          3
```

In this example I want the final result to be 3 when I select 1 from the "activity replaced by activity" table. This is because we start by 1 and this activity is replaced by 2. But two is also replaced with 3.

The numbers of activities is unlimited and also the "activity replaced by activity"
Is there some way to do this without using stored procedures/functions? Should be possible to create a view from this query.(so, the result can be used in joins with other data)

This example is simplified to illustrate what I need help with. The solution should not involve creating of new tables/or change data structure because it has to be used with an existing solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select ShouldBeReplacedWithActivityId as activityId, 1 as lev
      from table2
      where activityId = 1
      union all
      select t.ShouldBeReplacedWithActivityId, cte.lev + 1
      from cte join
           table2 t
           on cte.activityId = t.activityId
     )
select top 1 cte.*
from cte
order by lev desc;
```

If you have too many activities, then you will need to set the max recursion option.  You also need to be careful about cycles in the activities.

Comment: Thank you. I Will test with this :)

Comment: where is t defined/what is t?

Comment: `t` would be whatever table contains the data you posted in your original question. How do you think this query would work without referencing your table?